# Pass a list to asp.net drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am using a linq to xml query for the data to be poulated into a list from an xml file.

```
        var Customerlist = (from c in doc.Descendants("Customer")

                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Name = c.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString()
                                    }).ToList();
```

Trying to pass the list to a drop down list in asp.net in this fashion.

```
ddlName.DataSource=CustomerList;
```

I am able to debug and see that the datasource is getting the list ,but the dropdownlist in the asp.net page doesn't display anything.

Can some one  guide me where my mistake is ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `ddlName.DataSource=CustomerList;`  try `ddlName.DataBind();`
Also, it might be a good idea to set ddlName.DataValueField and ddlName.DataTextField before setting DataSource.

Here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd7t67ef.aspx) says about DataBind().